# Why not use energy instead of force for daily application?

Tags: forces, energy

I am quite sure my understanding of physics is not sound but I have observed that when I try to understand a concept using Energy makes more sense then using force. Why are physics concept based mainly on force?

Comment: We actually always need both concepts (and a few more) in classical mechanics. I don't know if we have a good answer that will satisfy your particular question, but you could take a look at this one: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/256446/ or this http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/258757/. In the last one Lubos Motl gives a viewpoint from a larger perspective than just classical mechanics, and there forces are kind of non-existent.

Comment: They're equivalent: "a system minimizes energy" is exactly the same statement as "a system moves in the direction it's pushed". But it's true that energy can be more intuitive. And in quantum mechanics, it's energy that is primary, not force.

Answer (score 0):

> Why not use energy instead of force for **daily application**?

Note that I highlighted "daily application". Your question is essentially the difference between engineering and physics. A lot of work has been done in the past decade to very carefully simulate interactions that appear to be dissipative using purely conservative (i.e., non-dissipative) models. This however requires the use of what is essentially a supercomputer, or what would have been deemed a supercomputer less than a decade ago.

The problem with those interactions that appear to be dissipative is that it is mathematically impossible to describe those interactions at a macro scale in terms of a Lagrangian or Hamiltonian formulation. You have two choices. One choice is to use an energy-based model. This requires talented people with lots of experience, a supercomputer, and if you're lucky, you'll get 15 seconds worth of simulated results after exercising that supercomputer overnight.

Alternatively, one could develop a dissipative force-based model that lets you calculate those interactions in an instant. There's an issue here; those dissipative models almost always use force rather than energy. Using energy doesn't make sense in this context. Those dissipative models typically cannot be expressed in terms of Lagrangian/Hamiltonian mechanics.

The key advantages of these dissipative models are that they are easily compressible and they do not require the use of a supercomputer to obtain 15 seconds of simulated results after spending hour upon hour of extremely expensive supercomputer time to obtain the desired result. The key disadvantage is that the dissipative models have a limited range of applicability.