# Help me Spot the difference between force and work/energy

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, work

Basically, I am a self-learner in physics because my school only provides physics lessons at first grade. So I have been confused with understanding the differences between force and work/energy.

Here is what I have:

1. Force is something that basically makes things accelerate (or can we say move?); correct me if I'm wrong.
2. Then work: what I get for work is an energy that is transferred when the object is moving? Again correct me if I'm wrong.

Then I came up with a strange thought that if an object is moving because of a force, then what does the work do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Force is something that basically makes things accelerate (or can we
>   say move?); correct me if I'm wrong.

A force may be thought of as any influence which *tends* to change the motion of an object. Note that I have emphasized the term "tends", because a force does not necessarily result in the acceleration of an object. Only a *net force* causes acceleration.

For example, I can exert a force on a wall. But if the ground exerts an equal and opposite force on the wall, the net force on the wall is zero and it will not accelerate.

By Newton's third law the wall exerts an equal an opposite force on me. But if the static friction force between my feet and the ground is equal and opposite to the force the wall exerts on me, the net force on me is zero and I do not accelerate. .

> Then work: what I get for work is an energy that is transferred when
>   the object is moving? Again correct me if I'm wrong.

Net work is done on an object that is subjected to a net force causing the displacement of the object transferring energy to the object. Again the key is the object must be subjected to a net force.

Taking the above example of me and the wall, the net force applied to each of  of us was zero. There is no displacement of either, and no work is done on either. Again the key is an object must be subjected to a *net force* in order for work to be done on or by the object.

But just because an object is moving does not mean it is subject to a net force and that work is being done, as discussed below.

> Then I came up with a strange thought that if an object is moving
>   because of a force, then what does the work do?

If the object is moving due to a constant net force applied in the direction of the movement, then the work done on the object in moving it a distance $d$ is $W=Fd$. And what that work does is to increase the object’s kinetic energy by an amount equal to the net work done on the object.

But you need to be careful. An object can be moving without a net force. This is the case when an object moves at constant velocity.

The work energy theorem states that the net work done on an object equals its change in kinetic energy. If the velocity of an object is constant, there is no change in kinetic energy and the net work done on the object is zero.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Force causes things to accelerate according to Newton's second law $a = F/m$. By implication, you could say it causes movement, but this is a consequence of the acceleration and also the time it has been accelerating. Since the object is now moving the force has to be applied over a distance (and a period of time) to keep the object accelerating.

This is where energy comes in. Energy is added and work done when a force is applied over a distance. It is given by the equation:

$W = Fs$

where $s$ is the distance over which the force was applied.

Let's take an example: say I try and push a car by leaning my weight against it, but I forget to take the brake off and so the car doesn't move. Although I am applying a force, it doesn't move and so no work is done. I could lean against the car all day, applying the same force, for no work done (in reality, due to the tension in my muscles and some flexing of the springs of the car there is still some movement and a build up of stresses and so some work done, but let's ignore that).

Now imagine I take the brake off and succeed in moving the car. To keep it accelerating and keep my weight against it I have to start walking and then running and so I am doing work to keep the force up and add energy to the car.

Answer (score 0):

Force is defined as the rate of change of momentum (momentum is mass multiplied by velocity) with respect to time. Work is the product of displacement and the component of force in the direction of displacement. If work is done, then the kinetic energy of an object changes. If a resultant force acts on an object then it accelerates. Work done is a change in energy; resultant force is related to acceleration.

$$F=\frac{\Delta p}{\Delta t}$$

$$W=F s \cos{\theta}$$

Comment: Force does not necessarily result in change in momentum, displacement, or work. Only net force.

Answer (score 0):

Possible [duplicate](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/256446/what-is-the-relation-between-force-physical-strength-enery-and-work?rq=1)

However, you might like hyperphysics at [GSU](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/work.html)
 [image]

and also

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Then I came up with a strange thought that if an object is moving because of a force, then what does the work do?

This is a good question and already has some good answers, see in particular the answer by @Bob D which explains about net forces and net work. This answer will supplement that one by describing the effect of the individual forces rather than the net force as I believe that it is important to understand both.

It turns out that the energy-related quantity that is most closely related to force is neither work nor energy but rather power. An individual (rather than net) force is the rate of transfer of momentum from one interacting system to another. The power associated with that individual force is the rate of transfer of energy from one interacting system to another (or in the context of engines the rate of the change of energy from one form to another).

Both energy and momentum are conserved quantities, so keeping track of them is very useful in physics. As such we are often interested in their rate of transfer between systems. So if we want to see fast a system gains momentum from another system we look at the force ($\vec F$) acting on the system. If we want to see how fast a system gains energy from another system we look at the power ($P=\vec F \cdot \vec v$) going into the system. In the definition of mechanical power $\vec v$ is the velocity of the material at the point of application of the force.

Both momentum and energy can go in or out of the system, and momentum is a vector so if there are equal and opposite forces acting on an object then the change in momentum will be zero, even if those forces are each providing power and increasing energy. An example of this would be two equal and opposite forces compressing a spring. The momentum from one force is canceled out by the other, but both forces have a positive power so the energy of the system increases. In this case it is not the kinetic energy (as described by the work energy theorem) but the internal energy.

Answer (score -1):

Force and work
(i)Force is define as the rate of change of moving with respect to time.
(i)work is the product of force and displacement.

Comment: Your force definition is not correct (do you mean acceleration?). Your work definition is way too simplistic and is not the definition of work in general.